# Loading local project static assets from CDN with RequireJS

Tags: node.js, express, gruntjs, cdn, rackspace-cloud

I have a single page application with node serving up the backbone app along with all the marketing material. I would like to serve all assets (JS, html, images) from our Rackspace Cloudfiles CDN to reduce load times as gzip files will be delivered as well as reduce the load on my node server.

What is the best way to automate this?

I need would need to:

- sync files after build to the CDN
- reference the CDN for all static assets in production mode

I found solutions with both Grunt and Node Modules which are used in my project.

[Grunt CDN](https://github.com/tactivos/grunt-cdn)
[Grunt Cloud Files](https://github.com/rtgibbons/grunt-cloudfiles)
[Node Asset Rack](https://github.com/techpines/asset-rack)

If I go with Grunt - which is my first choice,

1. How do I set the express application I am running on to serve from the CDN in production?
2. Is it better to use the asset manager for node since its serving all my assets anyway?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking here. Grunt CDN explains how to setup the grunt task for your build/deploy step to replace your urls with CDN URLs, regardless of app. If the URLs for those assets are dynamically generated, then you need to manually set the URL template where appropriate.

Comment: @rdodev I mean with regards to serving assets not listed in my templates but instead served directly to requirejs

Comment: I see. well that extra layer does complicate things. I'll look into that and report back if I find anything interesting.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I set the express application I am running on to serve from the CDN in production?

When you render your view you could pass it a flag to tell where to pick the assets from.

I've got an example here if you are interested. In my case I've got a flag on whether I am connected to the network or not (e.g. during a flight) to decide where to pick my JS files from:

```
<% if(isConnected) { %> 
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>    
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular-resource.min.js"></script>    
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>    
    <% } else { %>
      <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="/js/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="/js/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
      <script src="/js/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
    <% } %>
```

https://github.com/hectorcorrea/hectorcorrea.com/blob/master/views/index.ejs#L136

In my example, the value is hard coded, but you could easily pass Express dev/prod value to the view to get the same thing done automatically.

Comment: a lot of my assets are loaded directly with requirejs - any ideas for those